# CosmosDB Project Layout

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cosmosdb

Asking for advice and references.

Using Visual Studio, I have an Azure Web Apps project in my solution. Now, I'm programming my Stored Procedures for CosmosDB. Using the CosmosDB Emulator, I can simply insert the Stored Procedure code directly into the browser editor window. All good and fine, and everything is working beautifully.

I also have a NodeJS project sitting alongside my Web App project. This allows me to store the Stored Procedures as files. The associated Console App is able to connect and modify the CosmosDB Emulator as expected.

My question is, using Visual Studio, what is the best way to lay out my project, so that it's not done on napkins and prayers?

I'm wondering how I should be structuring my project layout and assets to align with current "best practices". Is there any information, articles or posts that you guys/gals have found that talk about this specifically? Would I be running all of these procedures against CosmosDB manually, or are there automated procedures people have devised? I would like to be able to test these stored procedures first, against the Emulator, and with little-to-no source code change, update staging.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just recently asked myself the same question regarding stored procedure migrations.. I am currently running a basic `Migrate` Method that will get stored procedure content from a js file and replace/create the stored procedure, this runs on startup (in startup.cs)

The main gist of the code below, you will need to create the very basic internal methods (comments welcome):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using App.Data.Access;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;

namespace App.Data.StoredProcedures
{
    public class Migrations : IMigrations
    {
        private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;
        private readonly IDocumentDbContext _documentDbContext;

        public Migrations(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment,IDocumentDbContext documentDbContext)
        {
            _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
            _documentDbContext = documentDbContext;
        }

        public async Task<bool> Migrate()
        {
            try
            {
                await AddUpdateBulkDeleteStoredProcedure();

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                throw new Exception("Error running CosmosDb stored procedure migrations,error" + exception.Message);
            }
        }

        public string GetStoredProcedureScript(string filename)
        {
            var script = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "App_Data", "CosmosDbStoredProcedures", filename);
            return IO.File.ToString(script);
        }

        public async Task<bool> AddUpdateBulkDeleteStoredProcedure()
        {
            const string storedProcedureId = "BulkDeleteStoredProcedure";

            var function = GetStoredProcedureScript($"{storedProcedureId}.js");

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(function))
            {
                throw new Exception($"Error running DocumentDb Stored procedure migrations, {storedProcedureId} content is empty");
            }

            try
            {
                await _documentDbContext.Client.ReplaceStoredProcedureAsync(_documentDbContext.GetStoredProcedureUri(storedProcedureId), new StoredProcedure {Id = storedProcedureId, Body = function});
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                // ignore
            }

            await _documentDbContext.Client.CreateStoredProcedureAsync(_documentDbContext.DocumentCollectionUri, new StoredProcedure {Id = storedProcedureId, Body = function});

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This was my initial thought, to read the function from the local file system. It’s a similar method to one I used years ago. I wasn’t sure if in the meantime, Visual Studio didn’t have some sort of “Publish” to CosmosDB feature added...

Comment: I haven't found anything out the box yet, but let its know if you do.

Comment: In lieu of any other suggestions, this seems to be the answer as of this time.